# Identifying power supplies / DC adapters

Tags: identification

I have a box of miscellaneous power supplies / AC adapters / transformers / "bricks" which have no information on them about what they are for. I am trying to match them up to the devices they belong with, including computer items, drives, cameras, and who-knows-what else. Some of the devices may have already been discarded.

Sometimes I have been successful typing the model numbers into Google, but usually I just get nothing,  or maybe a list of places to BUY the adapter. With some, I am told they are for a camera, for example, and that narrows down my search.

Does anyone have tips for identifying them? Wouldn't it be nice if there was a website with some sort of cross-matched list for these things?

Examples:

- Sino-American Model A30980 AC Adapter Class 2 Transformer;
- Ambico 45-8820 Class 2 Transformer Model 35 - 7.5 - 300C;
- AC Adapter (No Brand) Class 2 Transformer Model No. DBU120020

Comment: No help to you, but I mark every adapter with a label maker when it comes in. Sometimes the voltage and polarity is marked on the product- it's always marked on the adapter- that can help matching them up.

Answer (score 1):

Rarely does the manufacturer of a given device also manufacture its AC adapter. Therefore you really have nothing to go by except matching:

- **Voltage:** The adapter must provide the DC (or AC) voltage required by the device; no more, no less. *(Or if you have to, ideally no more than ±10%.)*
- **Polarity:** The tip and sleeve (inside and outside of connector) must be the correct polarity. This is usually indicated by the symbol:

  [image: DC polarity symbol]
- **Current:** The adapter must provide *at least* the current required by the device.
- **Power jack dimensions:** DC barrel jacks are not all the same dimension. If you find a suitable adapter for a given device, you might find the plug doesn't fit the jack.

Things that will hinder your efforts:

- Some adapters may not be labeled. Use a multimeter to measure output voltage and polarity.
- Some adapters are not regulated, meaning they were intended to provide the specified current only for a particular load. Thus, a "12V 500mA" adapter might measure 18V or more with no load. If you power a device that requires less than 500mA, it may provide a voltage that's too high.
- Some devices aren't labeled. Try searching online to determine the correct adapter, but be warned that the incorrect polarity or voltage could damage the device. *If it wasn't labeled, it probably deserved it. :)*

Please read [Olin's question and answer about selecting the correct power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/2028) for more information.